# HTML isn't working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm new to programming. I'm trying to call a function in html, but it isn't working. What's the problem? Thanks in advance. (Don't ask about the whole integration thing).

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="IntegrationCalculator.js"></script>
    <script>
        integrationCalculator(7);
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <p id="tester">
        Didn't work :(
    </p>
</body>
```

My javascript code:

```
var integrationCalculator = function (variable1) {
if (variable1 = 7) {
    document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML="WORKED";
}
};
```

Comment: This `if (variable1 = 7) {` should be `if (variable1 == 7) {`. The first one does assignment, the second does comparison. Consider using a JavaScript validator to look for these sorts of bugs. http://jshint.com/

Comment: ...also, keep your browser's developer console open during development. You'll see the TypeError resulting from the issue @j08691 described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First `if (variable1 = 7)` should be `if (variable1 == 7)`. Second, call your function after the element is loaded in the DOM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="IntegrationCalculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="tester">
        Didn't work :(
    </p>
    <script>
        integrationCalculator(7);
    </script>
</body>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v7sh9/)**

Comment: Hope it helped. If you feel this answered your question, you may want to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`integrationCalculator` is called before the `tester` paragraph is created. Therefore, an error is thrown and the execution of the script is stopped.